# Laravel how to change passport table names to start with capital letters?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-passport

I am trying to build and API, and I am using passport for authentication, the problem is I want all table names to start with capital letter for example "Oauth" instead of "oauth", how to achieve this without directly modifying the vendor files?

Comment: When you install passport, It generates a migration file, goto that migration file and change the name of the table as per your need

Comment: I believe you'll end up with lot of issues because of that. What is actual reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly modify table names but you can modify the model names that passport uses.
If you look at `Passport` Class there are static class variables:

```
    /**
     * The auth code model class name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $authCodeModel = 'Laravel\Passport\AuthCode';

    /**
     * The client model class name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $clientModel = 'Laravel\Passport\Client';

    /**
     * The personal access client model class name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $personalAccessClientModel = 'Laravel\Passport\PersonalAccessClient';

    /**
     * The token model class name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $tokenModel = 'Laravel\Passport\Token';

    /**
     * The refresh token model class name.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $refreshTokenModel = 'Laravel\Passport\RefreshToken';
```

and etc.
These are models that passport uses to communicate with database. You can make your own model and extend Passport models.

For example:

```
class MyOwnAuthCodeModel extends Laravel\Passport\AuthCode {
    
    public $table = 'Auth_codes';

}
```

Then in Passport `ServiceProvider` File you have to change models:

```
Passport::$clientModel = '\App\Models\MyOwnAuthCodeModel';
...
```

Then you have to make migration files to rename all passport tables:

```
Schema::rename('oauth_codes', 'Oauth_codes');
...
```

That steps is too much if you don't want to change table names in vendor migrations and models.

And it's ready to work correctly.

> Remember you have to do this for all passport tables and models.

Comment: how to access the PassportServiceProvider?

Comment: I mean "Then in Passport ServiceProvider File you have to change models" in what file? there is no PassportServiceProvider

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mean `RouteServiceProvider` or in `AppServiceProvider` depends on where you have put passport routes